# how to get the file

Tags: php, cakephp, amazon-s3

I have a file in Amazon S3 and the API returns an object. I want to transfer the files from Amazon to my local servers directory. The object has a url address too. It is just not clear to me how to use this object to transfer the file.

Comment: Which S3 API are you using for PHP?  Please provide info about which API you're using.  Also so people have something concrete to work with please include a snippet of code.

Comment: Using aws-sdk. I just called the method getobject in s3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP this is how you code it.

```
require_once '../aws-sdk-for-php/sdk.class.php';

// Instantiate the class.
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$bucket = '*** Provide bucket Name ***';
$keyname = '*** Provide object key name ***';
$filepath = '*** local file path to save the object ***';

// Save object to a file.
$response = $s3->get_object(
                    $bucket,
                    $keyname,
                    array('fileDownload'=> $filepath));
```

I hope this helps.